# Accessing relations from a DataRow when using DataSets

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset

I am trying to access the parent of a row but it always returns null.

I have two tables, one description a station and the other telling if the stations are "close" to each other.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GlobalStations] (
    [GlobalStationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    ....
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NearStations] (
    [OriginalStationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToleratedStationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

With constraints set on SQL Server to insure data is consistent.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NearStations]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NearStations_Original] FOREIGN KEY([OriginalStationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[GlobalStations] ([GlobalStationId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NearStations]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NearStations_Tolerated] FOREIGN KEY([ToleratedStationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[GlobalStations] ([GlobalStationId])
```

I have added the two table if the dataset, and I am now trying to access the GlobalStation when I have a NearStation row.

```cs
var nearStationsTA = new NearStationsTableAdapter()
var stations = nearStationsTA.GetData();
var st = stations[0];
var tid = st.ToleratedStationId;
var global = st.GlobalStationsRowByFK_NearStations_Tolerated; // Always NULL
```

I expected the generated code to do some kind of lazy loading, but apparently it does not do it.

How do I force the code to do the loading by itself?
Can I force the dataset to load every GlobalStation I use all of them anyway) to have the row when I need it?

Thanks